# Function as parameter Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, replace

I wish to replace some part of the string using some other string found with the help of regex. For generating the replacement string, I have to write a function. Below is my string in which I want to replace "{#string}" with something else.

```
var testString = "https://www.google.com/solution?region={america}&&country={usa}&&language={english}"
```

For testing purposes, I tried the below which works fine:

```
testString = testString.replace(regex, "")
```

But instead of `""`, I would like to have a block or function there which generates a replacement string based on the keys i.e. region, country and language and returns it. Below is what I tried and the error I am getting. What am I missing syntactically?

```
testString = testString.replace(regex, fun() : String {
    return ""
})
```

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The signature of the anonymous function you pass to `replace` is wrong. As the error message states the function needs to be of type `(MatchResult) -> CharSequence`.

This would work since `String` is a subclass of `CharSequence`:

```
val result = "Some String".replace(Regex("[S]"), fun(mr: MatchResult) : String {
    return "s"
}) // result will be "some string"
```

**Note:** Instead of the anonymous function, you could also use a lambda which can infer the parameter and return type:

```
val result = "Some String".replace(Regex("[S]")) {
    "s"
}
```

The `MatchResult` will be available as `it` then.

Comment: I do not know Kotlin and thus abandoned the attempt, but when I tried that on https://ideone.com/l1qtnw, it did not work for me.

Comment: @tevemadar the first argument of this overload of replace has to be a Regex not a String. I edited my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: Thank you. This is why I should not check new things from phone - I completely missed that detail despite of attempting to read the error messages and also checking the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html).

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
string.replace(regex) { /*do your logic here*/ }
```

You can also access the match result with the function, and it should return a CharSequence:

```
string.replace(regex) { matchResult -> "" }
```

Or reference a declared function

```
string.replace(regex, ::doMagic)

fun doMagic(matchResult: MatchResult): CharSequence {
    /*
     *some cool stuff
     */
    return ""
 }
```